# How can you compare two lists in such a way that you find out how many times a word from one list is in the second list?

Tags: python, performance

I have two lists, one containing true values selected by humans and a second list with extracted values. I would like to measure how well the pipeline is performing based on how many true values are contained in the extracted list. Example:

```
extracted_value = ["value", "of", "words", "that", "were", "tracked"]
real_value = ["value", "words", "that"]
```

I need a metric that describes:
3 out of 3 real values were extracted

For multiple Documents:
5 out of 10 real values were extracted
2 out of 3 real values were extracted
1 out of 9 real values were extracted

Based on the individual comparison, can I get a score that describes how well the extracted keywords perform on average across all documents?

Answer (score 1):

Will something simple like this work?

```
score = len([x for x in real_value if x in extracted_value])/len(extracted_value)
print(score)
>>> 0.5
```

Comment: Thats this helped: I Just changed the lists: score = len([x for x in extracted_value if x in real_value])/len(real_value)
print(score) and this works. Do you have an idea how to average on all documents?

Comment: how did you store that data for you document set? one in the example is for single document only, right? then you can get a sum of all scores and divide it by number of documents

Answer (score 1):

To check how many values are shared between extracted_value and real_value. I believe you're looking for the recall of your model, you can use set operations, specifically & (and) divided by your ground truth (real_values):

```
recall = len(set(real_value) & set(extracted_value))/len(real_values)
```

or if you want exactly which specific values are shared, which you could always take the `len` of:

```
shared_vals = set(real_value) & set(extracted_value)
```

If you want to then calculate recall with shared_vals:

```
recall = len(shared_vals)/len(real_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The metric you're looking for is [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall).
@sfat's solution works well for a single document, you can then get the average over multiple documents by `sum`ming the scores and then dividing by the `len` of documents.

For more advanced scoring for your retrieval, check the F-Score section of the linked article.